# Show that homomorphisms from Z to any group G is in bijection with elements of G

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

I was solving the following problem:

> b) Show that homomorphisms from $\mathbf{Z}$ to any group $G$ is in bijetion[sic] with elements of $G$.
>
> c) How about homomorphisms from $C_k$ (cyclic group with $k$ elements) to a group $G$? How many does there exist[sic]  from $C_3$ to $S_6$? From $C_2$ to $S_6$?

I am not able to understand the question and how to proceed.
Please help me in understanding the question.

Comment: For (b): any such homomorphism is uniquely determined by its value at the integer $1$.

Comment: The English is a bit weird. In b) they want you to prove that there exists (a natural) bijection from the set of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ to $G$. In c) they ask about the number of homomorphisms $C_k \to G$.

Comment: This exact question, including the use of an image rather than text, was posted earlier today, and then deleted after a comment indicated it wasn’t well written. Why is it being posted anew? Also, please do not use images in lieu of text: they can cause problems with some displays, they are generally not searchable within the site, and they are usually not compatible with accessibility software. This site supports excellent mathematical typography, and you should avail yourself of it.

Comment: I see you are making a habit of posting images instead of text. Please do not do so.

Comment: @BodhiVeda It is not bad practice to at least browse through the FAQ of a site when you join. In this case, it would have directed you to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  For $\Bbb Z$, the homomorphisms are completely determined by where you send a generator.  There are no relations among the elements ($\Bbb Z$ is a free group).  Thus we get a homomorphism $h:\Bbb Z\to G$ for every choice of $h(1)\in G$.

In contrast, for $C_k$, you don't always get a nontrivial homomorphism into $G$.  $C_k$ isn't free, as it is finite.  As a result, the order of the image of the generator must divide $k$.

Thus there are the number of elements of order $2$ from $C_2$ to $S_6$. (I count $75$.)

And the number of elements of order $3$ from $C_3$ to $S_6$. (I count $80$.)

See [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S6), as a double-check for the counting.