# Show that every homomorphism from Z to Z is equal to ϕn, for some n ∈ Z.

Tags: group-theory

So I think I have an answer for this question but I'm unsure if its right or not. I think it may be too simple???

Fix an integer n. Then ϕn : Z −→ Z, x -> nx is a homomorphism because
ϕn(x + y) = n(x + y) = nx + ny = ϕn(x) + ϕn(y).

I cant find anything else in my notes for this question!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: **Hint :** Prove that an homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is entirely determined by the image of $1$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345849/show-that-homomorphisms-from-z-to-any-group-g-is-in-bijection-with-elements-of-g?rq=1).

Comment: The image of a group homomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain, and all the subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some $n$.

Comment: Please use mathjax rather than ascii art. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).